# How to sideload my own/snapcraft example app?

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

Just trying snappy for the first time, wanting to develop an app but would obviously want to test it before pushing it to the app store.  I've been through the snapcraft tutorial but once you've created a snap how do you get it into a snappy machine?

I've seen posts about 'sideloading'(?) apps but can't work out how?

As a start - how would I load one of the snapcraft example apps into my KVM snappy instance? (one of the ones not in the app store)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Note that as you probably haven't signed your snap you will probably have to run:

```
sudo snap install /path_to_yoursnap/snapname.snap
```

after the `scp`

You can also try a `snappy-remote` install, which should look like this:

```
snappy-remote --url=ssh://ubuntu@webdm.local/ install snapname.snap
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you build the snap either using `snappy build` or `snapcraft`, sideloading is simply the process of installing your snap without going through the store (exactly what you're trying to do). An analog to this in the Debian packaging world would be installing a .deb via `dpkg` instead of using `apt-get`.

If you have SSH enabled on your KVM instance, use `scp` to transfer the generated .snap over. Once you're there, simply run `sudo snap install /path/to/my.snap` on the KVM instance, and you just sideloaded it. You'll see it now if you run `snappy list`.